# jenkins builds filtering based on build description

Tags: regex, view, jenkins, filter, build

Is there a way to filter out a job's builds based on description matching with build name. Each build name is set by build name setter plugin, and want to filter out with regex matched build-name with a view? I know there is search filter view per job description, the same way we need for build description.

Comment: Hopefully, you found an answer but otherwise, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768722/jenkins-filter-build-history-by-label-or-parameter) seems to be a good starting point