# Jenkins: Filter build history by label or parameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to filter the build history in Jenkins so that only builds with a specific label or parameter show up?

Let's say I have some job that is parametrized. One of the parameters is a simple string which can either be "experimental" or "official". Is there any plugin which lets me filter the build history to only show the "official" builds?

Comment: looking for same kind of plugin or method to do.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29768722/398670

Comment: Related: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters

The needed section for reading is "Filter by Job Parameterization"

Comment: this does not seem to work in the way i expected.  I have a job called joba, that accepts a parameter param.  If i run this joba twice, once with param=abc and once with param=def.  If I create a view using a filter based on the name=param value=abc, the view shows joba, but it shows build #2 with param=def, while I would like only those builds that had param=abc.

Comment: @Paul, me too looking for a plugin like you mentioned here.

Comment: This does not satisfy the question's requirements. They want to filter runs within a job. The View Job Filters plugin inspects the *most recent run's parameters* to decide whether or not to show *the whole job* in the list of jobs.

It doesn't filter the runs at all.

Answer (score 11):

## Quicksearch of builds (runs) + custom run descriptions

Out of the box Jenkins supports a quicksearch over the build history that matches by label (description). Anything you put in the label can be used in the search:

[image: show a quicksearch of build history]

... so you can use any plugin that can change the build label to add the info you want, then use quicksearch. The above example used the Pipeline plugin with the [Groovy postbuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin), but you could use anything you feel like; say the [description setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) or [job name setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin).

You can then inject things like parameters into the job name. It's ugly, and annoying, and verbose. And there's no convenient way to save canned filters. But it works.

This workaround has a number of deficiencies:

- You can't save filters
- You can't view the build trend for a given filter (parameter, branch, etc)
- You can't view the Pipeline history for just a filter

which is why many people use:

## Job templating - create duplicate jobs

If you want canned filters and convenient saved views, the widely used workaround at the moment seems to be to use the Jenkins Job Builder, a job template plugin, etc, to spawn lots of similar jobs. Use separate jobs to manage separate suites of parameters, etc. Then use Views to group up the jobs how you want.

## Write a plugin?

I haven't found any pre-existing plugin to do it. You could implement your own Item that provides a custom job display and/or override the "Build History" list, but I haven't found any canned ones yet.

The Build History UI element is the [`BuildHistoryWidget`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/widgets/BuildHistoryWidget.html) ([`BuildHistoryWidget.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/widgets/BuildHistoryWidget.java)). It implements `ExtensionPoint` so you can override it with an [`@Extension`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/Extension.html). You shouldn't need to patch Jenkins.

A Google search for `"extends HistoryWidget" -"class BuildHistoryWidget"` failed to find any existing implementations.

## Extend [Pipeline Stage View Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view)

If you use Pipeline (Workflow) jobs, you may wish to consider extending or modifying the Pipeline [Stage View Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view) to meet your needs.

It looks [like it's designed to be somewhat extensible](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/tree/master/ui). See [pipeline-staged.hbs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/blob/master/ui/src/main/js/view/templates/pipeline-staged.hbs).